# "ready" event is never called

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm programming my first Discord bot and I programmed it to output something to the console whenever it starts up, or in other words whenever `client.on("ready")` is called. However, I can't get it to actually fire and I don't know why. I have all Node dependencies installed, the bot is in the server and is able to send messages, and the first few lines of the program run fine.
What is the problem?

Here is the source:

```
console.log("Launching bot...\n");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with 
  ${client.users.size} users, in 
  ${client.channels.size} channels of 
  ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Serving 
  ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
});

client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.authot.bot) return;

  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) 
    return;

  const args = 
  message.content
  .slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ + 
  /g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === "ping") {
    let m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
    m.edit(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - 
    message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is 
    ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you correctly set the bot up in Discord? How are you running the script?

Comment: yeah i'm pretty sure i did it's in the discord server. and i'm running it with node from command line

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to use the [`.login`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login) method for your client, that's the reason why your `ready` event doesn't get triggered!

Here is the updated code, you just have to insert your top secret key from https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/

```
console.log("Launching bot...\n");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Bot has started, with 
  ${client.users.size} users, in 
  ${client.channels.size} channels of 
  ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Serving 
  ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
});

client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.authot.bot) return;

  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) 
    return;

  const args = 
  message.content
  .slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ + 
  /g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === "ping") {
    let m = await message.channel.send("Ping?");
    m.edit(`Pong! Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - 
    message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is 
    ${Math.round(client.ping)}ms`);
  }
});

client.login("YOUR TOP SECRET KEY")
```